# Downloading a PDF file in ReactJS works locally but doesn't work on Amazon Amplify AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, pdf, download

I have already found the solution to this issue and it is included in this post. This is just to alert anyone who is suffering through the same issue.

**The Problem**:
I was trying to get a PDF to download in my react app.
This is the embedded code for the download:

```js
import ResumePDF from "../../files/Resume.pdf";

// somewhere in a react functional component...
<a href={ResumePDF} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" download="zolyomi_resume.pdf">
    <Button>download</Button>
</a>
```

Now, I verified that the file **was in the correct location** and was being imported properly. Indeed, when I ran this *locally*, it had no issues whatsoever. The problem came when I deployed to AWS Amplify (committed to the linked github repo).

**The Solution**:
In AWS Amplify, there is a specific portion of the *App Settings* where you specify that certain file types are linked to certain extensions.

Basically, you have to **specify** that the .pdf file is a valid form of redirectable file.

1. Head to your AWS Amplify console
2. Navigate to the app having the issue
3. Select Rewrites and Redirects from the left sidebar

[image: Rewrites and Redirects]

4. Edit the rewrite that looks like a long Regex string. The pdf extension is **not included in this list** by default, so you have to add it. After the word `css` (or any other file extension) add the following: `|pdf`. Make sure that you keep this as a `rewrite` and not a `redirect`. It should look like this:

[image: long text]

5. Save, ensure it updates in the console, and then refresh the page. It should work now.

**TL;DR** Amazon Amplify makes you specify file types that are redirectable. By default, PDF is not. Other file types besides `css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json` are not either, so you have to add them in yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental issue here is that your `aws amplify` is missing an entry in the `rewrites & redirects` section. The default configuration for your app will have the following:

- `source address` -> `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>` with corresponding `target address` -> `/index.html`.

If you look more closely, the `regex` allows only certain file-types - and `pdf` is NOT a part of it. You can simply `edit` this `row` and change the `source address` to `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(pdf|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`. Notice that I have pre-fixed it with `pdf|` ... this should provide you the needed fix.

[image]

You can access the `redirects` section by going to your `aws amplify` app's home page, and then go to the `app settings` -> `rewrites & redirects`.
[image]

IMO the above is a hot-fix, and not a clean solution. A big `pdf` file can create packaging and serving troubles for you. The correct way to go about this is to drop these files into your `object-store S3` and configure the `redirects` correctly. You can read more about `redirects` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html). You can even automate these steps in your `amplify.yml`'s pre-build steps.