# failed to load pdf document on download in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a button that downloads my cv onto the device onClick for a website portfolio.
It works on my localhost but it returns this error when once it is pushed to AWS-Amplify.
[error on the aws-deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yYz6.png)

I changed my imports from relative to absolute but this hasn't fixed the issue.
The cv is currently in the root folder.

```
import resume from './KuroUsaResume.pdf'
import 'stylesheets/Home.css';


function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">

      .....
      
      .....

        <a href= {resume} download="KuroUsa's_Resume.pdf">
          <button className='home--download-button'>Download CV</button>
        </a>
        
      </div> 

      <div className="home--body">
        <img src={me} className="logo" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Home;
```

My jsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how this works locally.  The code `<a href={resume} ....>` doesn't make sense to me.  You are importing a PDF file's contents into `resume`, but then HREF of a link is set to the contents of the PDF ??

Comment: maybe you can store the Resume in AWS S3 or Amplify Storage and then use that publicly accessable S3 URL in the href of <a/> element ?

Comment: @GregFenton I'm not importing the contents of the file, I just want to reference the file to be downloaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "reference to the file" ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using this website

[Downloading a PDF file in ReactJS works locally but doesn't work on Amazon Amplify AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507437/downloading-a-pdf-file-in-reactjs-works-locally-but-doesnt-work-on-amazon-ampli)

I had to specify that a .pdf file was a valid redirectable file type, since it isn't there by default.